# Distance calculation inside of a window to the value of an external column

Tags: sql, sqlite

Here is a simple table:

```
DROP TABLE demo;
CREATE TABLE demo(x DOUBLE);
INSERT INTO demo VALUES (0.6), (1.1), (1.5), (2.0);
```

For each `x` value, I can collect its neighbours using windows. For Apache Spark, it is possible to use `collect_list` instead of `group_concat`:

```
SELECT 
    x,
    group_concat(x, ', ') OVER (ORDER BY floor(x) RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS neighbours 
from demo;
```

As a result, I will get the next table:

| x | neighbours |
| --- | --- |
| 0.6 | 0.6, 1.1, 1.5 |
| 1.1 | 0.6, 1.1, 1.5, 2.0 |
| 1.5 | 0.6, 1.1, 1.5, 2.0 |
| 2.0 | 1.1, 1.5, 2.0 |

I need to find not only neighbours, but their distances to the original `x` value, like:

| x | distances |
| --- | --- |
| 0.6 | 0.0, 0.5, 0.9 |
| 1.1 | 0.5, 0.0, 0.4, 0.9 |
| 1.5 | 0.9, 0.4, 0.0, 0.5 |
| 2.0 | 0.9, 0.5, 0.0 |

Please, could you help me to do this? By some way in `group_concat(x, ', ')` I need to call to the original `x` value. But, obviously, `group_concat(x-x, ', ')` returns only zeros.

You can test the code here: https://sqliteonline.com

Comment: Try ``concat(x-lag(x,1,x)OVER(ORDER BY floor(x) ),', '   ,x-x,', '   ,x-lead(x,1,x)OVER(ORDER BY floor(x) ))``

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your initial problem statement.

```
  SELECT 
  x, 
  coalesce(round(x - LAG(x) OVER (ORDER BY x ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING), 1) || ',', '') || 0.0 || coalesce(',' || round(LEAD(x) OVER (ORDER BY x ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING) -x, 1), '') as neighbours
  from demo
```